# Client side resizing image then back to form for submission (no Ajax)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, submit

I have been pulling my hair off trying to find a way to select an image (input type=file), run a method (on change=function blah(this)) to resize the image, then put the file back to the form (I know we cannot put it back to the input element due to security reasons)! I am after a solution for it without using Ajax. Why? I think I would spend more time changing the application than actually finding a solution for this. I need to upload the image with all the form data as I need to link ids across a couple of tables. So it would be a big problem uploading the file first (through ajax) and then later on associate Ids (I don't want do go down that road, hence why I am here with my question). I am using asp.net mvc5. I can upload the image without resizing it, but the images will have around 3 to 5 MB. This is too much to keep on the server (thousands os customers with multiple images each) but specially too long uploading (otherwise I would resize it on the server).
I have read about 20 different threads here where I could get good ideas, like the math calc to resize the image, use canvas, FileReader, readAsUrl, etc. But all the scenarios propose an async upload.
So my question is: is it actually possible to load the image through input file element, resize and somehow bring it back to the form for upload on a full postback?

Threads that I have checked:
[HTML input type=file, get the image before submitting the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802580/html-input-type-file-get-the-image-before-submitting-the-form)
[How to upload preview image before upload through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094012/how-to-upload-preview-image-before-upload-through-javascript)
[Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)
[Resize image before submit the form html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653041/resize-image-before-submit-the-form-html5)
[HTML5 Pre-resize images before uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333971/html5-pre-resize-images-before-uploading)
among many others! These are just a few examples.

Any help will be great!

Comment: Make this easier to read or nobody will help...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you should resize the image before saving it in the server.Of you have to save some other associated data then save the the image as a last process.I can help you if give the controller code and a description of when you want to save the image.